Handling Call Decline Actions with flutter_callkit_incoming When App Is Terminated
In my app, I use flutter_callkit_incoming package to manage incoming calls. But there's an issue: when I decline a call, when the app is terminated, the linked function is not executed.
    `FlutterCallkitIncoming.onEvent.listen((CallEvent? event) async {
      final CallMethods callMethods = CallMethods();
      switch (event!.event) {
        case Event.actionCallDecline:
          await callMethods.endCall(call: Call.fromMap(event.body['extra']));
          break;

        default:
      }
    });`

This should cancel the call, so the caller will see that the call has been declined. Actually it only works when the app is opened open. What can I do to execute it when the app is terminated?
